# Есть ли аналог setDefaultCloseOperation()?

Tags: java, javafx

Мне нужно сделать:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)
```

в JavaFX, именно так, я знаю, что есть команда

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Но мне нужно сделать, что бы на нажатие кнопки `Закрыть` вообще ничего не происходило.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> event.consume());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```